# Keep checkbox status after page reload/refresh ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working around a script that keeps one or multiple checkbox values checked on page reloaded or refreshed. The code below was executed to maintain the checkboxes values but it's not working. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<script>
            function onClickBox() {
                let checked=$("#check").is(":checked");
                localStorage.setItem("checked", checked);

            }
            function onReady() {

                let checked="true"==localStorage.getItem("checked");
                $("#check").prop('checked', checked);
                $("#check").click(onClickBox);
            }
            $(document).ready(onReady);

</script>
```

This line of code `return '<input type="checkbox"  id="check" href="#"' + 'order_id="'+ data + '">Yes</>';` allows admin to check a checkbox, after which the code takes the ID and then runs the check_payment.php that has the query that inserts yes to that ID row.

```
 aoColumnDefs: [
           {
                aTargets: [6],
                mData: "userId",
                mRender: function (data, type, full) {
                     return '<input type="checkbox"  id="check" href="#"' + 'order_id="'+ data + '">Yes</>';
                    //return '<button href="#"' + 'order_id="'+ data + '">Yes</button>';
                }

            }
         ],
         language: {
            url: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/English.json'
            }
});
$('#example').on( 'click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
            var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
            var order_id = data['order_id'];
            console.log(order_id);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'check_payment.php',
                data: "order_id=" + order_id,   
            });
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VanillaJS approach. We have `document.querySelector` now, so in *my* view, jQuery has been depreciated for a while. As far as I can tell your logic is solid, so I can only assume it's one of the jQuery calls that's breaking, and I honestly don't know which one.

```
// get element #check
var checkbox = window.check;

// checking and setting
isChecked = () => localStorage.getItem("checked") == "true";
setCheck = (v) => checkbox.checked = v;

// event handlers
onClickBox = () => localStorage.setItem("checked", checkbox.checked);
onReady = () => setCheck(isChecked());

// bindings
checkbox.addEventListener("click", onClickBox);
document.addEventListener("load", onReady);
```

Edit: I think what might be happening is the onLoad handler (or onReady, with jQuery) is never firing because the code is embedded in the body. If the script is in the head, use the eventHandler; if the script is in the body, just call `onReady()` after setting the click handler for the checkbox.

Comment: Hi Christian.
Thanks for you answer. 
Unfortunately, doesn't work for me. 

Basically, what this line of code does, 
`code` return '<input type="checkbox" id="check" href="#"' + 'order_id="'+ data + '">Yes</>';  is, when a checkbox is checked, takes the order_id, runs a script and enters the value as yes in the database. The next thing I want it to do is when I reload/refresh the page it should keep the checkbox status checked. 

I have tried many other ways to achieve this. I cannot figure out what I am missing.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please find additional codes after _This line of code_